# How to call Add Task action in custom tab to show task for sales order?

Tags: acumatica

I have customized the Sales Order screen and added a new tab to show Task for the sales order as shown in the Opportunity screen. I am trying to add action to the task grid and call the existing add task action.

How to i add the Grid toolbar button and call the existing functionality?

Regards,
R.Muralidharan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize out-of-box **Activity** data view defined in **SOOrderEntry** Graph. **CRActivityList** implements New Task, New Event etc. Link Activity data view to Grid control.
[image: Activity Data view]

To add Grid Tool bar button, drag Button control to Grid node in designer:

[image: Drag1]

[image: Drag2]

Once dropped, specify Toolbar button properties:

[image: Toolbar Button]